# How to setup angularjs app first time?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs and trying to setup new app but its always giving me error angular is not define , Please let me know what is right way to start angular app .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>First App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
anuglar.module('app',['ngRoute']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "views/main.html"
    })
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, someone else did - but I think people would like it better if you added the full text of the error message more prominently at the top of the question. Put it in its own paragraph, with the fully available text and stack trace if you can. In my opinion your question got answered anyway, but the stack overflow community also likes to have questions look nice and be easy to read for anyone else who has the same question in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

below `app.js`

You have to put it before `app.js`

Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

You used angular library file twice

Use either this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

or this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```